# Trying to make a speech recognition program with python but the program doesn't seem to hear me

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-to-text-api

the first except block runs every time i speak into the microphone, please help!

'''

```
import speech_recognition as sr  

# get audio from the microphone                                                                       
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Speak:")                                                                                   
    audio = r.listen(source)   

try:
    print("You said " + r.recognize_google(audio))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results; {0}".format(e))
```

'''

Comment: Why do you have to exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

I think your `RequestError` is a result of the Google API reaching its limits. Google says:

> Audio longer than ~1 minute must use the uri field to reference an audio file in Google Cloud Storage.
>   [See here for the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas#content)

So you need to create an account [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/) and use the API key given. Then upload the audio to the cloud and then use that link as a parameter in your program.

This is the only solution Google gives. Hope it helps :)

Comment: brother It is "Not" throwing request error it throws UnknownValueEror, please help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

## **THIS SHOULD HELP IT**

### *instead of **'+'**  I added **','** in the print statement of try block*

```
    import speech_recognition as sr  

    # get audio from the microphone                                                                       
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Speak:")                                                                                   
        audio = r.listen(source)   

    try:
        print("You said " ,r.recognize_google(audio))
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Could not understand audio")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Could not request results; {0}".format(e))
```